Is there anything else we can do to help newbies ask appropriate questions?
Yes, this partly duplicates a lot of past discussion, but I felt it needed to be reopened. Feel free to shoot it down, ideally suggesting which old question should be revived.
At the moment we have four closed questions at the top of the list. I don't disagree with any of those decisions, and workplace is far from alone in having such bursts, but it's not a great look.
I know there's theoretically an onboarding document we want people to read, though I've never seen it. It's pretty clear that if it does cover these issues, people are not reading it, or at least are thinking it doesn't apply to them. Check boxes saying "I have read, and agreed to abide by, these rules" don't really seem to work, even when there is a script that requires all pages of the document to have appeared on screen before the box can be checked. Maybe it needs a TL;DR version that summarizes the rules, reduced to snappy bullet points in large bold italic (red?) font, with links to more detail as we have in the close menu?
If I was designing the stack exchange UI, I would be inclined to replace [closed] with a short reason, eg [closed: offtopic] or [closed: needs specialist advice], so even without viewing the question text folks can see what the issue was, understand our communal standards, and learn therefrom. Multiple reasons would also just look less hostile than [closed][closed][closed]. But given SE's speed of response to past suggestions, even if somebody who can make that change is reading this, I don't expect it to happen until several years out.
Is there anything else we can do without having to alter SE itself, or that they might actually accept as important, cheap, and urgent enough not to defer?
(Endless September, alas, does not mean that they're aren't more confused newbies in September...)

When are we going to finally reach the conclusion that more writing is not going to solve the issue? It doesn't matter where you put the text or how well it is summarized, the solution is never going to be giving people more things to read. Drop the reputation requirement for posting on meta and chatting so they can talk to people about the site and how it works before they post an "inappropriate" question. Forcing newbies to compose a post before they can get any feedback from a person on whether they're doing it right is just mean.
When we on-board someone at our company, we don't just throw a stack of documentation at them and lock them in a room until they've read it all, then have them start working and expect they'll do everything well because it's all right there in the documentation. Why would we expect that methodology to work here on a site full of volunteers and random strangers on the internet when it doesn't work when someone's paycheck is on the line?
Some people will never care about what is good for the site, but more people would care if they felt like part of a community instead of just an anonymous user with no connection to anyone here.

I'm not sure this is something Stack Exchange would let us do, and I'm not sure it's the best solution, but it does make some sense. Actively assist first time posters before they embarrass themselves. Admittedly they should be reading for a while before it's they post so they can see what is expected, but folks often don't or don't know how to apply it to their question.

@keshlam Honestly I am disengaged from SE because they’re blocking access to the content so I don’t care much. I just had to point out that every time this comes up, the only solution people think of is to either add to/reformat the already extensive help text, or put in some mechanisms to force people to read it, while ignoring that the majority of people asking questions here do not have the same English reading level that the people suggesting reading-as-a-solution do. It’s more difficult than y’all imagine for some users to read and understand even the tour.

It's a good point; thank you! The bullet-point summary idea might help that part of the community, if written with that in mind, by reducing the amount and complexity of reading.

@keshlam Not trying to be a negative Nancy here, but bulleted lists do not miraculously overcome a literacy/EFL/dyslexia issue. I still feel like you aren't understanding that many people can not learn stuff just by reading about it, no matter how slowly and loudly you type it. This is actually one potentially great application for an AI chat bot. Someone could ask it questions using natural language and get an answer from a model trained on the site's norms instead of asking some general purpose chat bot to explain what "comments are ephemeral" means.

I am not looking for a miracle. I'm looking for an improvement. Even if only incremental. If someone was willing to put in the effort to write a chat bot that was immune to hallucination, that might be a great answer. But the last thing we need is a bot giving out authoritative wrong answers.

@keshlam There are already bots giving out authoritative wrong answers - you can't stop people from using them. There's a reason chatGPT is immensely popular even though it gives out objectively bad information sometimes. I'm trying to explain to you that you've got a giant blind spot. Giving people more or different things to read is not going to improve anything. It's just doing something to feel like we're taking some sort of action when we don't have the ability to easily make meaningful changes, or even accurately measure a change's impact.

I am trying to find a way to give them less to read but enough to understand the basics. I am trying to suggest a TL;DR abstract, with more detail that they can follow up on if they want to understand the rationale. I don't know if it's possible. But what we have now is not working very well, and I think we need to leave ourselves room to brainstorm for what might be better.
